# Wallet.fromV3 is not a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, module.exports

I'm using [`ethereumjs-wallet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet), and in my development node environment, a call to `Wallet.fromV3` is working without issue. On my production installation, an error occurs

```
TypeError: Wallet.fromV3 is not a function
    at extractPrivateKey (/usr/src/app/dist/blockchain/library.js:83:23)
    at sendTransaction (/usr/src/app/dist/blockchain/library.js:113:3)
    at Object.callback (/usr/src/app/dist/blockchain/library.js:1052:5)
    at sendTxCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:533:29)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:293:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/src/app/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/src/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/src/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
```

`console.log` in my dev environment:

```
   Wallet function Wallet(priv, pub) {
      if (priv && pub) {
        throw new Error('Cannot supply both a private and a public key to the constructor');
      }
    
      if (priv && !ethUtil.isValidPrivate(priv)) {
        throw new Error('Private key does not satisfy the curve requirements (ie. it is invalid)');
      }
    
      if (pub && !ethUtil.isValidPublic(pub)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid public key');
      }
    
      this._privKey = priv;
      this._pubKey = pub;
    }
```

`console.log` in production

```
Wallet { hdkey: [Getter],
  thirdparty: [Getter],
  default:
   { [Function: Wallet]
     generate: [Function],
     generateVanityAddress: [Function],
     fromPublicKey: [Function],
     fromExtendedPublicKey: [Function],
     fromPrivateKey: [Function],
     fromExtendedPrivateKey: [Function],
     fromV1: [Function],
     fromV3: [Function],
     fromEthSale: [Function] } }
```

Is it something to do with the way `Wallet` is exported from `node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/dist/index.js`?

```
exports.default = Wallet;
```

Despite [the recommendation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet) of loading `Wallet` via: `const { Wallet } = require('ethereumjs-wallet')`, it's being loaded this way: `const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet')`, because it does not work properly in development with the former syntax.

The versions of `ethereumjs-wallet` and `truffle-hdwallet-provider` are consistent on both environments.

```
-- ethereumjs-wallet@1.0.0 
-- truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.17
```

Any idea what is happening on my production system?

Comment: Are the versions for node used in dev vs prod the same? It seems like your dev environment may be using an older version of node.

Comment: I'm using `v11.15.0` in both environments.

Comment: Then the `const { Wallet }` syntax should be working in both environments. That you're not using that syntax is why you're getting the exception you listed. All you say about why you're not using that syntax is "because it does not work properly in development" which isn't enough to troubleshoot anything.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with ethereumjs-wallet is exporting Wallet in 1.0.0. Reverting to 0.6.4, is a workable solution for now.